# Using fastlane to make build, with error no provisioning profiles

Tags: fastlane

I run the fastlane to make a build, but get the following output:

> [17:51:56]: fastlane finished with errors
>
> [!] To reset the provisioning profiles of your Apple account, you can use the `match nuke` feature, more information on https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/match

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't use fenced code blocks (using three backticks). Instead, select the code block and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. This will indent the block by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. However, in many cases error output is better served with a blockquote (by prefixing with `>`) since it isn't often formatted for narrow screens and content in blockquotes wraps.

Comment: two repositories attempting to re-sync a single provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

Fistly, run `match nuke development`, it will clear the profiles and certs on apple's develop site.

Then, run `match development`, pay attention to run in the project folder.